# What is the meaning of combination "from in front of "

Tags: meaning, phrases, prepositions

"He could watch the Governor twist arms, offer incentives and drop, one by one, with matchless guile, the veils from in front of threats."

What is the meaning of the last clause? Why author uses such a strange combination "from in front of"?

Comment: Apparently he is exposing the threats by removing the veils that were placed in front of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"He could watch the Governor twist arms, offer incentives and drop, one by one, with matchless guile, the veils from in front of [the various] threats [that he faced]."

"from in front of" is a common phrase, I think the confusion is that "threats" is ambiguous. The text is from a book on [power and politics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vEsaCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=%22He%20could%20watch%20the%20Governor%20twist%20arms,%20offer%20incentives%20and%20drop,%20one%20by%20one,%20with%20matchless%20guile,%20the%20veils%20from%20in%20front%20of%20threats.%22&source=bl&ots=v3JvptsTV_&sig=wCFgpaI3nUHNFQCyTHyCODaiCzs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBgafstMjPAhWBBiwKHdYaAwsQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22He%20could%20watch%20the%20Governor%20twist%20arms%2C%20offer%20incentives%20and%20drop%2C%20one%20by%20one%2C%20with%20matchless%20guile%2C%20the%20veils%20from%20in%20front%20of%20threats.%22&f=false). As Governor, he would face many threats to his position and power. The text is saying that although his enemies would try to hide their threats from him, he was skillful at uncovering them.